# Symfony 5 cache:clear php.CRITICAL: Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

I am encoutering the following error with Symfony 5 when trying to

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

I know how I could patch that (memory_limit=-1) but I want know why I have this error.

Error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 32230840 bytes) 
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Toile./vendor/twig/twig/src/Lexer.php on line 157
>
> 15:50:13 CRITICAL  [php] Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32230840 bytes)
>
> ```
> [
>   "exception" => Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError {
>     -error: [
>       "type" => 1,
>       "message" => "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32230840 bytes)",
>       "file" => "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Toile./vendor/twig/twig/src/Lexer.php",
>       "line" => 157
>     ]
>     #message: "Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32230840 bytes)"
>     #code: 0
>     #file: "./vendor/twig/twig/src/Lexer.php"
>     #line: 157
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> In Lexer.php line 157: Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 32230840 bytes)

I am unable to track from where this error comes from.

I removed all twig templates from my project, I clearing the cache manually but nothing .. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If it takes too much memory that's, because it takes too much memory so nothing you can do beside increasing the limit in the php.ini or via the command line, eg. `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/console ca:cl`

Comment: Thanks, I increasing the limit in the php.ini to 256MO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `bin/console cache:clear` command takes up a lot of memory. I don't think it's because of the twig files.

setting up `memory_limit=-1` is sort of you are disabling the memory limit, means giving unlimited of memory to run PHP. Please check your php.ini file and adjust the memory_limit.

Note that you might have 2 php.ini files for PHP, one for web and one for command-line use. Use `php -i` to see the loaded ini file.

Use this command `php -i | grep 'Configuration'` to grep the output from command line.

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing that, but I wanted a better solution. I finally increased the memory_limit of php.ini to 256MB.

Comment: It's not a solution, you just removed the problem at all.
Why there is a need to allocate more memory when you are purging sth?
This is the root cause whom you just ignored.

Comment: It's not a valid anwser, so. No permanent solution has been proposed

Answer (score 0):

Check all your Project Directory if some of code doesn't contain any lines like this: `ini_set('memory_limit'`
— Symfony parses all classes and takes into account it.
For example, in my case there was: `ini_set('memory_limit', '42M');` and 42MB was not enough to run console task.